# Override JComponent paint() method or not

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I have a class that extends JComponent and I want a method which draw the component, apparently I must not call paint() directly but repaint(), except that I need to paint in a graphics so I don't have much choices

Should I do :

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    //draw things
}
```

or

```
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    this.paint(g);
    //draw things
}
```

or I don't call paint() at all ? It is said that paint() call others methods and especially transfert to subcomponents and I don't want to loose that

Comment: You should 3) read the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: Also check out [these search links](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+graphics+paint+paintcomponent) for similar questions and answers.